# How to solve this puzzle by invariance principle?

Tags: contest-math, invariant-theory, invariance

I have the following puzzle-

> You initially have $15$ $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ and $12$ $\color{brown}{\text{yellow}}$ balls.You can do one of the two things with the balls-
>
> 1. $\text{Swap}-$You can swap the balls.This means if you start with $x$ red and $y$ yellow balls,after the transformation you have $y$ red and $x$ yellow balls.
> 2. $\text{Exchange}-$You can exchange $3$ red balls for $2$ yellow balls provided that you have atleast $3$ red balls.
>
>    - Now,if possible after how many transformations (you can use either of the rules mentioned above as $1$ or $2$ any number of times and in any order) will you have $5$ red balls and $5$ yellow balls?
>    - Also,what is the total number of combination of the number of balls you can have?

How to solve this with invariance preferably.If not possible other methods are  welcome too!

Thanks!!

Comment: Note:  yellow font on a yellow background $=$ strictly invisible.

Comment: @lulu Does "=" stand for assignment operator or equality operator?

Comment: Neither, I suppose...maybe it's a color blindness thing but pre-edit I could see a painful blur...

Comment: @lulu Haha... changed the color...:-)

Comment: Just to clarify the question, you aren't insisting that the change be done in $1$ or $2$ moves are you?  That is clearly not possible.  You just mean that we can use the transformations in any order we like as often as we like, yes?  And, $\#2$ can be done in both directions or only one way?

Comment: @lulu You can use the two rules of swap and exchange any number of times and in any order you need to reach (5,5) and what do you mean by both directions?

Comment: I mean, if I have only $2 $ yellows can I exchange them for $3$ reds?

Comment: the difference red-yellow, modulus 5, is an invariant except for the sign, so you can't get 5,5

Comment: @lulu Most probably you can.Though I copied the exact question here.Its not mentioned explicitly...

Comment: @Exodd Can you provide a more explanatory answer?

Comment: I'm thinking you can't because of the second question.  If you could then there would be no limit to the number of combinations (you could get as many balls as you wanted).

Comment: @lulu What would be your approach if the second question was not given?

Comment: I would search for a congruence obstruction, as @Exodd did.  That settles the $(5,5)$ case at once regardless of whether you can invert the second transform or not.  The remaining question is whether you can get every combination which passes the congruence test.

Comment: @Exodd is right: if the original value of $r-y\bmod 5$ is $k$, then your two rules restirict all subsequent values to $\pm k\bmod 5$. So you can't go from $(r,y)=(15,12)$ with $k=3$, to $(r,y)=(5,5)$ with $k=0$.

Comment: @lulu That's nice!You can write an answer...it will be more helpful:-)

Comment: Oh, @Exodd should write it up.  No question about it.

Comment: @TonyK How is $r-y\pmod5$ invariant ?For example if we do Exchange transformation on 15 red and 12 yellow,we get 12 red and 14 yellow.The difference changes from 3 to 2...

Comment: @tatan: $2\equiv -3\bmod 5$. Note that I wrote "$\pm k\bmod 5$".

Comment: @TonyK How did you deduce that this will always hold true even after any number of transformations?

Answer (score 6):

After each exchange the parity between red and yellow changes (from same parity to different parity, and vice versa). Moreover, each exchange reduces the total number of balls by $1$.

At the start, we have $27$ balls and different parities.
If the final state has a total of $k$ balls, we will need to remove a total of $27-k$ balls; in other words, we will need to perform $27-k$ exchanges.
If a state has $k$ balls, with $k_r$ red balls and $k_y$ yellow, then at the end one of the following must hold

- $k$ is even $\iff$ $27-k$ is odd $\implies$ $k_r$ and $k_y$ are the same parity
- $k$ is odd $\iff$ $27-k$ is even $\implies$ $k_r$ and $k_y$ are different parities

Now, if $k_r$ and $k_y$ satisfy the above relations, is the final state achievable?

Observe that a state $(k_r,k_y)$ is reachable if and only if the state $(k_y,k_r)$ is reachable, so it's fair to assume without loss of generality that $k_r\geq k_y$.
For any given configuration, let $d=k_r-k_y$, so that in the beginning we have $d=3$.

An exchange makes $d\mapsto d-5$ and a swap makes $d\mapsto -d$. In particular, $d\pmod5$ is either $3$ or $-3\equiv 2$, so it can never be $0$. The state with $k_r=k_y=5$ is hence not reachable.